# I can't upload code to my esp8266 (arduino ide V.2.1.0, windows 11 )

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266, windows-11

I'm on window 11 and arduino ide V.2.1.0 I want to cade my ESP 8266 bt

```
. Variables and constants in RAM (global, static), used 28008 / 80192 bytes (34%)
║   SEGMENT  BYTES    DESCRIPTION
╠══ DATA     1496     initialized variables
╠══ RODATA   920      constants       
╚══ BSS      25592    zeroed variables
. Instruction RAM (IRAM_ATTR, ICACHE_RAM_ATTR), used 59143 / 65536 bytes (90%)
║   SEGMENT  BYTES    DESCRIPTION
╠══ ICACHE   32768    reserved space for flash instruction cache
╚══ IRAM     26375    code in IRAM    
. Code in flash (default, ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR), used 231620 / 1048576 bytes (22%)
║   SEGMENT  BYTES    DESCRIPTION
╚══ IROM     231620   code in flash   
esptool.py v3.0
Serial port COM3

A fatal esptool.py error occurred: could not open port 'COM3': FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, 2)
```

[i use this port to conect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ertTL.png)

[and i have install ESP additional boards before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY0JQ.png)

before i reset(like reinstall window by "reset this pc" function on window) my PC It work correctly but when i reset it and install arduino ide back i get this problem